# jQuery each store returned data in to string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looping through a bunch of p tags to get the value. I am trying to check that there are no duplicate entries when a user enters a new value.

How would I loop through the p tags, and store the text value in to an array or even a string so that I can late check for duplicates?

My p tags are structured like so:

```
<p class="favorite-tag-name">My Favorite Storage</p>
```

I have tried to loop through to store the values into a variable, but it seems to only store the last value, instead of all.

```
var catNames = jQuery( ".favorite-tag-name" ).each(function() {
                                                jQuery(this).text();
                                        });
```

I want to loop through and stored all of the values into an array or string so that I can crosscheck with the new entries.

Answer (score 2):

Use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
var catNames = jQuery(".favorite-tag-name").map(function () {
    return jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).text());
}).get();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d49mQ/)